# (react-csv) Assign csv header that have the same column name but from different tables

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two tables , orders and readers. Both of them have column name status.
Now for csv reports header it will be

```
this.clientsList = [
{label: "Readers Status". key: "status"}
{label: "Orders Status". key: "status",}
]
```

Expected: the csv header for readers status will display status of readers, orders status will display order for status
Actual: the csv header will display both column as readers status because it is"status" that comes first

Answer (score 0):

The status is paired with the name of the results from the query of an API.

```
SELECT Customer Status as "C_Status"
```

so pair it with the same name for the KEY in CSV header.